# Can a false implications converse ever be true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have tried wrapping my head around this, and i cant seem to find a false implication whose converse is true. I dont think it is possible.

In other words a false implication would be

if not p, then q.

Its converse would be

if q, then not p

I dont think theres an example that would satisfy this criteria.

The problem is asking to give an example of a false implication whose converse is true. Any tips

Comment: "If it's not a triangle then it's a square" is false, but "If it's a square then it's not a triangle" is true, right?

Comment: You do realize that your question is the same as asking, "Can a true implication's converse ever be false"? If $P\implies Q$ is a true implication whose converse $Q\implies P$ is false, then $Q\implies P$ is a false implication whose converse $P\implies Q$ is true.

Comment: What is a false implication for you? Because "if not $p$, then $q$" is just an implication. Nothing about it indicates any truth value to it.

Answer (score 2):

"If $1 = 1$, then $1 = 2$" is false. "If $1 = 2$, then $1 = 1$" is true.